# How to get the user input from form_tag into the controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form like this:

```
<div id="page_wrapper">
    <p>Please insert the usernumber of the user that you want to make admin</p>
    <%= form_tag admins_path do %>
      <%= text_field_tag "account" %> <br/> <br/>
      <%= submit_tag "Make admin" %>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

and I want to get he userinput in the account text field into the controller. I have the naming right. In the controller I have something like this

```
def create
    getUserNum = :account 
end 

def admin_params
    params.require(:admin).permit(:account)
end
```

So I want to get the userinput from the account textfield and store it into a variable called getUserNum. But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create
    ad_params = admin_params
    getUserNum = ad_params[:account]
end 

def admin_params
    params.require(:admin).permit(:account)
end
```

Comment: it didn't work, it says `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Correct. Because there's no `admin` key in params. Look at your logs.

Comment: how to add the admin key in params ? Thanks

Comment: @jvillian the error should be `param is missing or the value is empty: admin` if `admin` is not present in params.

Comment: @Jocker_mix Please refer updated code. earlier method name and the variable name was same which may cause the issue,

Comment: @KiranDodani - actually, that sounds right. Good call.